# Auto-Select Radio After onchange event.

Tags: javascript, jquery, business-catalyst

I am using a CMS (Business Catalyst) and I am setting shipping options for a site when a user checks out. I want to auto-select the shipping option after a user enters their zipcode/postcode but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

***HTML***

```
<input value="" id="shippingPostcode" name="shippingPostcode" class="discountcodeInput" onchange="RetrieveShippingCosts(3416418,188536);return false;">
```

*Note: HTML code cannot be changed. This is system generated.*

***JS***

```
var $radios = $('input:radio');
$('#shippingPostcode').change(function() {
   $radios.trigger('click');
});
```

I know when the zip is entered and the `onchange` in the HTML happens it is retrieving shipping cost using the USPS API. Thinking that the radio is not created until after the onchange event of the above HTML to display I could add a delay to get this to work. I attempted this code:

```
var $radios = $('input:radio');
$('#shippingPostcode').change(function() {
   $radios/dealy(1000).trigger('click');
});
```

but that did not work either. How do I select the radio button after the HTML onchange event happens?

Answer (score 1):

instead of using jQuery delay try js setTimeout:

```
var $radios = $('input:radio');
$('#shippingPostcode').change(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $radios.prop('checked', true);
    }, 1000);
});
```